# How to get the data saved in a USER_ID?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The data is saved correctly, as you can see in the following image:

[image]

I use this code:

```
btnDatos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String name = nameTextView.getText().toString();
            String email = emailTextView.getText().toString();
            String id = idTextView.getText().toString();
            String idJuego = idffTextView.getText().toString();


            Map hopperUdates = new HashMap();
            hopperUdates.put("name", name);
            hopperUdates.put("email", email);
            hopperUdates.put("id", id);
            hopperUdates.put("idFreeFire", idJuego);

            mDatabase.child("Usuario").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).updateChildren(hopperUdates);
    }
});
```

And to obtain the data I use the following code:
     mDatabase.child("Usuario").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

```
            int idJuego = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            idffTextView.setText(idJuego);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But it does not show the data and when I test it on the device the app is closed. What would be the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all data then create model class and then stored datasnapshot into that model class like this

Model model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);

Or you want single data then just get the child like this

String idJuego = dataSnapshot.child("childname").getValue().toString;

And then set that string into textView.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert from Integer to string...

int idJuego = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            `idffTextView.setText(String.valueOf(idJuego ));`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are saving the `uid` as the key of your user object and in the same time as a property within the user object, to set that id to your `idffTextView`, please use either the following lines of code:

```
String idJuego = dataSnapshot.getkey();
idffTextView.setText(idJuego);
```

Or:

```
String idJuego = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class)
idffTextView.setText(idJuego);
```

Please note, that in both cases the `id` is of type `String` and **not** `int`.